# Pointers to a virtual member functions

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

Consider the following code

```
class BASE
{
  public:
            virtual void test_f(){std::cout<<"BASE::test_f\n";}
};

class DERIVED:public BASE
{
    public:
            virtual void test_f(){std::cout<<"DERIVED::test_f\n";}
};

void (BASE::*p_base)() = &BASE::test_f;
```

p_base is a pointer to a class member function but it is polymorphic.
That means that

```
DERIVED a;
(a.*p_base)();
```

will print DERIVED::test_f

How could i get the pointer to a test_f of the base class to make NON polymorphic call?

Comment: Why are you trying to create a pointer to a polymorphic function? Doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: Yes i know. I'm just curious how the things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class BASE
{
  public:
            virtual void test_f(){std::cout<<"BASE::test_f\n";}
};

class DERIVED:public BASE
{
    public:
            virtual void test_f(){std::cout<<"DERIVED::test_f\n";}
};

int main()
{
  // prints Derived
  void (BASE::*p_base)() = &BASE::test_f;
  DERIVED a;
  (a.*p_base)(); 
  auto f = std::mem_fun(&BASE::test_f);
  f(&a);
  
  // prints Base
  a.BASE::test_f();
  auto callLater = [&a]() { a.BASE::test_f();};
  callLater();  
}
```